# Dealing with .NET generic dictionaries in F#?

Tags: f#

1. I am not a functional programmer.
2. I am learning F#.
3. I got a problem here.

Let me start from following piece of code:

```
type XmlNode(tagName, innerValue) =
    member this.TagName = tagName
    member this.InnerValue = innerValue
    member this.Atts = Dictionary<string, obj>()
```

I don't use F# `dict` because (as I know) that one is readonly, however I obviously need to modify my attributes.
So I am really struggling to make it pure functional way:

```
type XmlNode with member this.WriteTo (output:StringBuilder) = 
    output.Append("<" + this.TagName) |> ignore
    //let writeAtts = 
    //    List.map2 (fun key value -> " " + key + "=" + value.ToString())
 (List.ofSeq this.Atts.Keys) (List.ofSeq this.Atts.Values)
    //    |> List.reduce (fun acc str -> acc + " " + str)
    //output.Append((writeAtts)) |> ignore
    output.Append(">" + this.InnerValue + "</" + this.TagName + ">") |> ignore
    output
```

The code I commented out was my (probably stupid) attemp to use mapping and reduction to concat all the atts in the single correctly formatted string. And that compiles OK.

But when I try to access my Atts property:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let root = new XmlNode("root", "test")
    root.Atts.Add("att", "val") // trying to add a new KVP
    let output = new StringBuilder()
    printfn "%O" (root.WriteTo(output))
    Console.ReadLine()|>ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

...new attribute does not appear inside the Atts property, i.e. it remains empty.

So:
1) help me to make my code more functional.
2) and to understand how to deal with modificable dictionaries in F#.

Thank you.

Comment: Formatting and indentation is off. Please show your code exactly as you have it.

Comment: F# `dict` is not readonly. `dict` is a function that creates an `IDictionary<_,_>`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - It's an `IDictionary<_,_>`, but attempting to modify it will throw an exception.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: The problem here is actually pretty subtle. Your property `Atts`'s body (`Dictionary<string, obj>()`) is executed each time the property is accessed.  This means that all changes are effectively transient because you create and return a new dictionary the next time you get the property.  You can use `member val Atts = Dictionary<string,obj>()` instead and the body will only be evaluated once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First,** your immediate problem: the way you defined the `Atts` property, it's not one value that is "stored" somewhere and is accessible via property. Instead, your definition means "every time somebody reads this property, create a new dictionary and return it". This is why your new attribute doesn't appear in the dictionary: it's a different dictionary every time you read `root.Atts`.

To create a property with a backing field and initial value, use `member val`:

```
type XmlNode(...) =
   ...
   member val Atts = Dictionary<string,object>()
```

### Now, answers to some implied questions.

**First order of business:** "modify the attributes" and "purely functional" are contradictory ideas. Functional programming implies immutable data. Nothing changes ever. The way to advance your computation is to create a new datum at every step, without overwriting the previous one. This basic idea turns out to be immensely valuable in practice: safer threading, trivial "undo" scenarios, trivial parallelization, trivial distribution to other machines, and even reduced memory consumption via persistent data structures.

Immutability is a very important point, and I urge you not to glance over it. Accepting it requires a mental shift. From my own (and other people I know) experience, it is very hard coming from imperative programming, but it is well worth it.

**Second:** do not use classes and properties. Technically speaking, object-oriented programming (in the sense of message passing) is not contradictory to functional, but the Enterprise flavor that is used in practice and implemented in C++, Java, C# et al., *is* contradictory, because it emphasizes this idea that "methods are operations that change an object's state", which is not functional (see above). So it's better to avoid object-oriented constructs, at least while you're learning. And especially since F# provides much better ways to encode data:

```
type XmlNode = { TagName: string; InnerValue: string; Atts: (string*string) list }
```

(notice how my `Atts` is not a dictionary; we'll come to this in a bit)

Similarly, to represent operations on your data, use functions, not methods:

```
 let printNode (node: XmlNode) = (* we'll come to the implementation later *)
```

**Third:** why do you say that you "obviously" need to modify the attributes? The code you've shown does not call for this. For example, using my definition of `XmlNode` above, I can rewrite your code this way:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let root = { TagName = "root"; InnerValue = "test"; Atts = ["att", "val"] }
    printfn "%s" (printNode root)
    ...
```

But even if that was a real need, you shouldn't do it "in place". As I've described above while talking about immutability, you should not mutate the existing node, but rather create a new node that differs from the original one in whatever way you wanted to "modify":

```
let addAttr node name value = { node with Atts = (name, value) :: node.Atts }
```

In this implementation, I take a node and name/value of an attribute, and produce a *new* node whose `Atts` list consists of whatever was in the original node's `Atts` with the new attribute prepended.

The original `Atts` list stays intact, unmodified. But this does not mean twice the memory consumption: because we know that the original list never changes, we can reuse it: we create the new list by only allocating memory for the new item and including a reference to the old list as "other items". If the old list was subject to change, we couldn't do that, we would have to create a full copy (see "[Defensive Copy](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15)"). This strategy is known as "[Persistent Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)". It is one of the pillars of functional programming.

**Finally,** for string formatting, I recommend using `sprintf` instead of `StringBuilder`. It offers similar performance benefits, but in addition provides type safety. For example, code `sprintf "%s" 5` will not compile, complaining that the format expects a string, but the final argument `5` is a number. With this, we can implement the `printNode` function:

```
 let printNode (node: XmlNode) =
    let atts = seq { for n, v in node.Atts -> sprintf " %s=\"%s\"" n v } |> String.concat ""
    sprintf "<%s%s>%s</%s>" node.TagName atts node.InnerValue node.TagName
```

For reference, here's your complete program, rewritten in functional style:

```
type XmlNode = { TagName: string; InnerValue: string; Atts: (string*string) list }

let printNode (node: XmlNode) =
    let atts = seq { for n, v in node.Atts -> sprintf " %s=\"%s\"" n v } |> String.concat ""
    sprintf "<%s%s>%s</%s>" node.TagName atts node.InnerValue node.TagName

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
   let root = { TagName = "root"; InnerValue = "test"; Atts = ["att", "val"] }
   printfn "%s" (printNode root)

   Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
   0
```

Comment: Does my way of defining type in "constructor" and your way (inside `{...}` block) makes your code more "functional"? Why? And one more question regarding immutability. So it is perfectly fine to do things like `let addAttr node name value = { node with Atts = (name, value) :: node.Atts }` (and never mind we are acting on a property). From the other hand, it is undesirable to do things like `Atts.Add(...)`? Because second example "modifies" the data however first one... modifies the data as well, doesn't it? I can't understand the difference.

Comment: Your way of defining a class is not intrinsically different than the record definition that I used. However, it does have a number of disadvantages: (1) record definition is shorter, (2) in a record definition, I only mention each field once, (3) records are guaranteed to be immutable by the compiler, (4) records support the `with` syntax, (5) records support pattern matching. (perhaps there are more, but these jump to mind immediately).

Comment: My definition of `addAttr` _does not_ modify anything. That was a key point. There is no data mutation going on. Please re-read the explanation I gave right after the definition.

Comment: So I see `let addAttr node name value = { node with Atts = (name, value) :: node.Atts }` will RETURN a new node. Which is exactly the same like `return new XmlNode(...);` in C#, right? Probably my non-functional mindset is an obstruction to uderstand the benefits. So for me it seems that after each call to `addAttr` I need to deal with a new, different object. So I am forced to have lots of `let nodeWithAddedAttr = addAttr ...`. Is that normal for functional code? Or I againg missing a whole point?

Comment: Yes, you do need to deal with a new, different object. However, this does not lead to a whole bunch of `let nodeWithAttr` lines. In most cases you would apply a bunch of such operations by piping, so you don't have to give a name to each intermediate result. But even if you do give them a name, it can be the same name: F# supports name shadowing.

Comment: Thanks for your pricise and deep answer, Fyodor. It was very helpful.

Comment: From your comments, it seems that you are not merely "learning F#", but rather "started learning F# just now". Since you are so new, I would encourage you to do some preliminary reading before rushing to implement things. Attempting to translate your existing C# experience into F# usually does not end well. While it is possible to do everything that you would do in C#, doing so will not give you any benefits that F# offers. Specifically, I would recommend https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ as reading material. It is wonderful.

Comment: The biggest probem I am facing now is a undescribely strange syntax. It does not look clear and.. maybe natural? for me. But at the same time I am trying to understand the conceptual difference between functional way and OO. I've heard and red many times about 'stateless' algorythms.  You pointed where I was going to break this rule and modify my object. Hope next time I won't repeat such a silly mistake ;)

Comment: The word "strange" literally means "something I haven't seen before". The syntax is only "strange" to you, because you grew up on the curly-braced syntax.